# Trying to submit one Javascript form, and two forms submit instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two independent forms with different id, but when I am trying to submit one of them, they both submit at the same time. Maybe the JS code can be simplified as both forms have the same number of columns?

```
        <form method="post" action="#" id="formMor" class="Morning">
            <table id="formMor" class="Morning">


            <button id="save" class="Morning1" type="submit">Save</button>

        </form>



        <form method="post" action="#" id="formEven" class="Evening">
            <table id="formEven" class="Evening">

            </table>

            <button id="save" class="Evening1" type="submit">Save</button>

        </form>
```

and script.js

```
'use strict';


$(document).on("formEven").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var routineType = $("#formEven").attr('class');
    var newFormData = [];
    jQuery('#formEven tr:not(:first)').each(function(i) {
        var tb = jQuery(this);
        var obj = {};
        obj['Nr.'] = i;
        tb.find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
            obj[this.name] = this.value;
        });
        newFormData.push(obj);
    });
    console.log(newFormData);

});

$(document).on("formMor").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var routineType = $("#formMor").attr('class');
    var newFormData = [];
    jQuery('#formMor tr:not(:first)').each(function(i) {
        var tb = jQuery(this);
        var obj = {};
        obj['Nr.'] = i;
        tb.find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
            obj[this.name] = this.value;
        });
        newFormData.push(obj);
    });
    console.log(newFormData);
});
```

Comment: `$(document).on("formEven").submit` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly setting the submit handler, the prototype for on is `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )` you're passing in an id.
Since you selected the document and used `.on()` I'm going to assume you want to use event delegation.
Also, you have duplicate ids in your HTML, each id should be unique.

```
$(document).on("submit", "#formEven", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var routineType = $("#formEven").attr('class');
    var newFormData = [];
    jQuery('#formEven tr:not(:first)').each(function(i) {
        var tb = jQuery(this);
        var obj = {};
        obj['Nr.'] = i;
        tb.find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
            obj[this.name] = this.value;
        });
        newFormData.push(obj);
    });
    console.log(newFormData);

});

$(document).on("submit", "#formMor", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var routineType = $("#formMor").attr('class');
    var newFormData = [];
    jQuery('#formMor tr:not(:first)').each(function(i) {
        var tb = jQuery(this);
        var obj = {};
        obj['Nr.'] = i;
        tb.find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
            obj[this.name] = this.value;
        });
        newFormData.push(obj);
    });
    console.log(newFormData);
});


<form method="post" action="#" id="formMor" class="Morning">
    <table id="formMor-table" class="Morning">


    <button id="save-formMor" class="Morning1" type="submit">Save</button>

</form>

<form method="post" action="#" id="formEven" class="Evening">
    <table id="formEven-table" class="Evening">

    </table>

    <button id="save-formEven" class="Evening1" type="submit">Save</button>

</form>
```